# I want to compare alphanumeric strings in same column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with details of family members staying in a particular locality. Since these are government data, it has lot mistakes. Like in one column 'houseno', there a 2 values 'Ti 303' and '303' which are same house numbers.

In the end, I want Ti 303 to be updated with '303'. (As these are  family members living in same house)

Similarly 'P-101' and 'P/101' are same houseno's and I want it to be converted to either 'P-101' or 'P/101'. I tried difference, substring etc but of now use to me. Please help!

Comment: Post the queries which you have tried, sample data and expected output. Chances to get an answer will increase.

Comment: do you just want to ignore the part that isn't a number ? What if the number is first ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I don't think it's that easy, the OP clearly states he wants to keep `P-` or `P/` in his data. he needs to normalize it, but I think the rules are going to be a little more obscure then simply extract the number.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I should have been more specific. I meant when comparing the values. But you have a good point, how to determine which value to keep

Comment: You need to work out whether the mistakes are consistent, otherwise you would need to manually update every row. If the mistakes are not consistent (which they probably aren't), how can you work out the logic to apply to your update procedure?

Comment: There is no way I can do it manually. There are some million rows in the table. @t-clausen.dk No I dont want to ignore non numeric parts. Just that they need to look similar (as that particular house belongs to members of same family)

Comment: @Lukos - Yes you are right. Few mistakes are consistent like the one mentioned 'P-' & 'P/' . Another pattern could be 'Ti - 303' & '303' wherein I have to make it '303' for both rows. Next pattern, '1-101' & '1/101'...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `REPLACE` command.  For the two examples give you could hard code it as follows:

```
select REPLACE('Ti 303','Ti ','')
select REPLACE('P-101','P-','P/')
```

You would use `REPLACE` in your `UPDATE` command and not as a `SELECT` obviously.

If you have a list of strings to replace in a column with an update then you could put these into a table.  Then use this in your `REPLACE` command for the string pattern to be replaced.

Comment: The problem is that I have millions of rows and it can be 'Ti 303' or 'Br 405' or 'P/1010' or anything. Hence, can't hard code. I will surely make another table so that I have 2 tables with same columns to compare with. But the problem is that I cannot manually select all the string from such a big database. I am looking for something which can detect the pattern and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to strip out the characters to compare the content?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_GetNumberPart (@strMixedString VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @NumberPart INT
   -- Get the next non numeric character position
   SET @NumberPart = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strMixedString)
   -- While there are non numeric characters remaining
   WHILE @NumberPart > 0
      BEGIN
      -- Remove the non numeric character from the string 
      SET @strMixedString = STUFF(@strMixedString, @NumberPart , 1, '' )
      -- Get the next non numeric character position
      SET @NumberPart = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strMixedString)
   END
   -- Spit out the cleansed string
   RETURN ISNULL(@strMixedString,0)
END
GO

SELECT dbo.FN_GetNumberPart(HouseNo) 
from TblAddresses
```

Comment: The better alternative would be to use the SQL CLR fn in the place of standard UDF like shown above FN_GetNumberPart.  The SQL CLR would be fast and much more performant than an ordinary UDF.

Comment: You're quite right. Any idea what versions being used?

Comment: @SimonUK SQL Server 2012